# How to display loading animation before content when checkbox is checked?(Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I display content after an animation when I click on checkbox material. So I would like when I click on checkox to display only the animation first and after 5s or a period of time to display the text. I attached the code! I will appreciate any help! Thanks!

component

```html
<mat-checkbox #small (change)="0">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
<p *ngIf="small.checked">Small paragraph</p>
<div *ngIf="small.checked" class="loader"></div>
```

typescript behind te component

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ur3newtwo';
  show = false;
}
```

module

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
.loader {
    border: 4px solid #cccccc; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 2px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 different variables to control the appearance of the text and the loader, then use a timeout to wait before changing the variable that will make the text appear. For example:

```
<mat-checkbox #small (change)="toggleCheckbox($event.checked)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
<p *ngIf="showText">Small paragraph</p>
<div *ngIf="showLoader" class="loader"></div>
```

And in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    showText = false;
    showLoader = false;

    toggleCheckbox(checked: boolean) {
        if (checked) {
            this.showLoader = true;
            // Use a timeout to wait 5 seconds before showing the text
            setTimeout(() => { this.showText = true; }, 5000);
        } else {
            this.showText = false;
            this.showLoader = false;
        }
    }
}
```